# How to stub a function that doesn't belong to a class

Tags: flutter, testing, mocking, mockito, stub

I have a widget that is trying to get the userID by calling `getUserID` function that is defined in different file. How can I stub that function so that it returns the dummy userID.

**utils.dart**

```
String getUserID() {
  return User.ID
}
```

Test will have a widget that calls this function.

Comment: can you add the class that uses this function? If you do dependency injection via the constructor, you can simply pass a mock of the `utils.dart` class while testing the consumer of this class and mock the behavior. If your intention was to [mock a static method](https://rieckpil.de/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito-java-kotlin/), Mockito also supports this.